A book where a woman adopts children from the woods and finds out they are shifters
She is a park ranger or something like that. She then later meets a guy who also turns out to be a shifter.

What's a shifter? When did you read that book? Where? Do you remember how the cover looked like?

I can't speak for the OP, but "shifter" is a not uncommon synonym for "lycanthrope", like werewolves.
